# change the error message background color not text color customize TextInputLayout in android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

How to change the error message popup background color not text color customize TextInputLayout in android Kotlin

I want error design like this [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbXXx.png)

plz help me out for getting this solution. i am new to development android Kotlin.

Comment: Can you share the code in order to show what you have already tried and what is/is not working?

Answer (score 0):

For TextInputLayout there is a setBoxBackgroundColor function that accepts color(int) parameters. TextInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundColor((colorValue)) you can change your background color with this function.

Comment: Is it your own design or are you using default Android TextInputLayout? Because if you are using default TextInputLayout setBoxBacgroundColor should work. If you designed your own TextInputLayout with xml you can directly change your background color from resource file. Like this 

      android:background="@color..."

Comment: I am using TextInputLayout